# C++ Winapi Listbox getting selected Item using LB_GETSEL/LB_GETCURSEL

Tags: c++, windows, listbox, visual-studio-2017

So I started a standard windows project and added a listbox with a bunch of Items. If I click on an Item of the ListBox i wanted to recieve either the text of the Listbox or the itemdata i set before. So if the user clicks on the listbox I tried to get this information on multiple ways (from the Internet i tried to adapt to my problem) shown in the second code window. The problem is, neither LB_GETSEL, nor LB_GETCURSEL returns a value that I can use correctly. The value is always -1 or LB_ERR which is obviously not an useful value. Im using the MessageBox to visualize the return value of my SendMessage. What is my mistake?

*standard window code*

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
case WM_CREATE:
{


    LBTest = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
        , L"LISTBOX", NULL
        , WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL 
        , 7, 7, 300, 600
        , hWnd, (HMENU)19, hInst, NULL);
    std::wstring str;
    for (int l = 0; l < 210; l++)
    {
        str = std::to_wstring(l);
        int pos = SendMessage(LBTest, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str.c_str());
        SendMessage(LBTest, LB_SETITEMDATA, pos, (LPARAM)l);

    }

    break;
```

*standard window code*

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Menüauswahl bearbeiten:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        case 19:
        {


            int count = SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);

            int iSelected = -1;

            // go through the items and find the first selected one
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                // check if this item is selected or not..
                if (SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETSEL, i, 0) != LB_ERR)
                {
                    // yes, we only want the first selected so break.
                    iSelected = i;
                    break;
                }

            }
            std::wstring check = std::to_wstring(iSelected);
            MessageBox(hWnd, check.c_str(), L"wasd", MB_OK);

            //---------------------------------
            /*

            DWORD dwSel = SendMessage(hWnd, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);

            if (dwSel != LB_ERR)
            {
                std::wstring str;
            SendMessage( LBTest, LB_GETTEXT, dwSel, (LPARAM)str.c_str());
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"Error", L"test", MB_OK);
            }

            //--------------------------------------------------------


            //int lbItem = (int)SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
            //int i = (int)SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETITEMDATA, lbItem, 0);
            */
            break;
        }
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
```

*rest of window code*

**edit:** I tried to change the Code due to suggestions from the Comment Section but the Programm still does not Work. The suggestion included LBN_SELCHANGE as a condition for my command callback but i'm not sure wether this callback can be made in the MainWindow callback or needs its own callback.
edited full programm code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Testproject.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
const UINT WM_WINDOW_UPDATE = WM_APP + 0;

HINSTANCE hInst;                               
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            
HWND Button1,LBTest;




ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);




int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
 UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);




LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_TESTPROJECT, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
MyRegisterClass(hInstance);


if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
{
    return FALSE;
}

HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance,    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TESTPROJECT));

MSG msg;


while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
{
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//

//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_TESTPROJECT));
wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_TESTPROJECT);
wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//

//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
hInst = hInstance; //

HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
  CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

if (!hWnd)
{
  return FALSE;
}

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

return TRUE;
}

//

//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)
{
case WM_CREATE:
{


    LBTest = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
        , L"LISTBOX", NULL
        , WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL 
        , 7, 7, 300, 600
        , hWnd, (HMENU)19, hInst, NULL);
    std::wstring str;
    for (int l = 0; l < 210; l++)
    {
        str = std::to_wstring(l);
        int pos = SendMessage(LBTest, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)str.c_str());
        SendMessage(LBTest, LB_SETITEMDATA, pos, (LPARAM)l);

    }

    break;
}
case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);

        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
            case LBN_SELCHANGE:
            {
                /*
                int count = SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);
                int iSelected = -1;
                // go through the items and find the first selected one
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    // check if this item is selected or not..
                    if (SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETSEL, i, 0) != LB_ERR)
                    {
                        // yes, we only want the first selected so break.
                        iSelected = i;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                std::wstring check = std::to_wstring(iSelected);
                MessageBox(hWnd, check.c_str(), L"wasd", MB_OK);
                */
                //---------------------------------


                DWORD dwSel = SendMessage(hWnd, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);

                if (dwSel > 0)
                {
                    std::wstring str;
                    SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETTEXT, dwSel,     (LPARAM)str.c_str());
                    MessageBox(hWnd, str.c_str(), L"test", MB_OK);
                }
                MessageBox(hWnd, L"Check", L"test", MB_OK);
                /*


                //int lbItem = (int)SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
                //int i = (int)SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETITEMDATA, lbItem, 0);
                */
                break;
            }   
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
case WM_WINDOW_UPDATE:
{
    g_i = static_cast<int>(wParam);
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, nullptr, TRUE);
    break;
}
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        //TODO: Zeichencode, der hdc verwendet, hier einfügen...



        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}

// Meldungshandler für Infofeld.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
switch (message)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
    {
        EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    }
    break;
}
return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: You are unconditionally trying to retrieve the selected item in your `WM_COMMAND` handler, without even evaluating, whether this is a `LBN_SELCHANGE` notification. `LBN_SELCHANGE` is not the only notification sent to the control's parent. Who knows, maybe you are handling a notification that is sent prior to your listbox being fully populated. Plus, your `LB_GETSEL` loop is wrong. It terminates on the first item, that doesn't produce an error (not the first selected item).

Comment: I fixed the LB_GETSEL loop by simply requesting a value greater than 0. Anyways, this did not fix the problem. I also added a switch case for LBN_SELCHANGE although i suspect that this request will not be handled properly in the Callback of the Main Window. Im not sure If i have to do that and when i have to, i don't know how. I'm pretty new to C++

Comment: Also, ES_AUTOVSCROLL is not a list box style.

Comment: thanks but that still did not fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer of this problem. First of all, i had to understand, how the data input from the listbox works. If I interact with the listbox, a WM_Command message is send. This message contains a wparam which is nothing else than a unsigned integer, which has 4 bytes in windows applications (correct me if i'm wrong). These 4 bytes can be split into 2 messages, the LOWORD and the HIWORD, each of them containing 2 bytes. So if I interact with the listbox I get the WM_Command Message from Windows telling me that someone interacted with an object of my window and 2 informations in the wparam. The first one is the LOWORD which contains the actual object I interacted with. In this example it's the (HMENU)19 i assigned to the ListBox at the CreateWindowEx. But the HIWORD still contained Information about what has been done with the Listbox. There are several options including wether the Textbox is focused or not and wether there was a change of the selected Item. It turned out that there never was an information about a select change incoming, no matter what I clicked in that listbox. So I found out that, for that message entering your messageloop, you need to specify in your CreateWindowEx of your listbox, that this message gets send from Windows to your program. You do that with a LBS_NOTIFY in your dwStyle properties. In my case the fixed CreateWindowEx looked like that:

```
    LBTest = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
        , L"LISTBOX",NULL
        , WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL| LBS_NOTIFY
        , 7, 7, 300, 600
        , hWnd, (HMENU)19, hInst, NULL);
```

After fixing that, I just had to fix the message handler so that it looked like that:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);

        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
            case 19:
            {
                switch (HIWORD(wParam))
                {
                case LBN_SELCHANGE:
                {
                    int count = SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0);
                    int iSelected = -1;
                    // go through the items and find the first selected one
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        // check if this item is selected or not..
                        if (SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETSEL, i, 0) > 0)
                        {
                            // yes, we only want the first selected so break.
                            iSelected = i;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    break;
                }
                }
                break;
            }   
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
```

iSelected is then the selected itemnumber of your listbox. You can send that to a LB_GETTEXT to get the current text of the selected Item like that :

```
std::wstring check ;
SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETTEXT, iSelected, (LPARAM)check.c_str());
```

You can also get the same result by doing this:

```
                    std::wstring str;

                    DWORD dwSel = SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);


                    if (dwSel > 0)
                    {
                    std::wstring str;
                    SendMessage(LBTest, LB_GETTEXT, dwSel, (LPARAM)str.c_str());
                    MessageBox(hWnd, str.c_str(), L"test", MB_OK);
                    }
```

It is probably a faster solution than the first one, because you don't have to go through all of your listbox items.